# How could a custom cursor adaptor handle multiple layout?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am a newbie on Android Developing.

I would like to have a listview which contains 2 layout

```
USER_ID | NAME | FOOD

1       | John | Apple
1       | John | Banana
```

Which indicates that have 2 food preference. I would like to use the custom CursorAdapter to populate the data into the UI. I would like to show the layout in this way

```
NAME (First list item)
FOOD1 (Second list item and it should repeat afterwards)
FOOD2
FOOD3
```

In order to get this work I built 2 listview layouts - one for name display and one for showing preference food. However as the list item has only 2 entries the CursorAdapter, it ran only two times. So my app runs run like the following

```
John
Banana
```

It missed the apple.

Here is my bindView code in CursorAdapter

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_NAME: {
            String nameString = cursor.getString(Fragment.COL_QUESTION);
            viewHolder.questionView.setText(nameString);
            break;
        }
        case VIEW_TYPE_FOOD: {
            String foodString = cursor.getString(Fragment.COL_ANSWER);
            viewHolder.answerView.setText(foodString);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to get 3 items loaded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please check if you are getting viewType in bindView as VIEW_TYPE_NAME, VIEW_TYPE_FOOD, VIEW_TYPE_FOOD

Comment: Thanks. I got the VIEW_TYPE_NAME for the first iteration and the VIEW_TYPE_FOOD for the second iteration. As I use different font for different view so it is not possible to be confused.

Comment: I think the main problem is I want to get it run 3 times (as UI shows 3 columns). However it just run 2 times (as data has only 2 entries).

Comment: your question doesnt make sense to me. What are you trying to do? Just display a user and their food preference? The standard way would be to create a layout for the row in the list view which you can then populate with the data

Comment: To be honest I am not sure about my implementation method. So @DanielH you are right it might not make sense at all. I will try to change the layout.